# How to specify that a object created from a generic Data Container Class can only contain data of a certain type (say NSString) in Objective-C:

Tags: objective-c, generics

These are the interface definitions of the two classes I am using to create a generic LinkedList.

When I create a particular instance of the SList class, how can I specify that all the LinkedListObjects that will be linked to it should be of a specific type.  For e.g:  NSString.

I am trying to mimic "Type hint" feature I have seen in Objective-C. For e.g:  **NSArray < NSString * > *someArray;**

```
@interface SList : NSObject
@property LinkedListNode *head ;
@property NSUInteger size ;

-(void) insertFront:(id)newItem ;
@end


@interface LinkedListNode : NSObject
@property LinkedListNode *nextNode ;
@property id nodeData ;

-(void) insertAfter:(id)data ;

-(instancetype) initWithNextNode:(LinkedListNode *)nextNode andData:(id)nodeData ;
-(instancetype) initWithData:(id)nodeData ;
@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emulate what you see in the NSArray.h header. You need to make proper use of `ObjectType`.

Something like this:

```
@interface SList<ObjectType> : NSObject
@property LinkedListNode<ObjectType> *head ;
@property NSUInteger size ;

-(void) insertFront:(ObjectType)newItem ;
@end


@interface LinkedListNode<ObjectType> : NSObject
@property LinkedListNode *nextNode ;
@property ObjectType nodeData ;

-(void) insertAfter:(ObjectType)data ;

-(instancetype) initWithNextNode:(LinkedListNode *)nextNode andData:(ObjectType)nodeData ;
-(instancetype) initWithData:(ObjectType)nodeData ;
@end
```

Then you would create it something like this:

```
SList<NSString *> *list = [[SList alloc] init];
[list insertFrom:@"some string"];
```

Comment: Thanks @rmaddy for the answer (the fish) and teaching how to fish!

Comment: One thing I see is that we can't use ObjectType in the implementation.  It looks we have to use id in the implementation.  You may want to add this to your answer.